# LOGIC APPS - Having Issues Appending a text file to a Text file Blob

Tags: logic, azure-blob-storage, azure-logic-apps

I have 2 CSV Blob files; I need to append one to the other. I can't seem to get this to happen; maybe I am doing something wrong. These are 2 txt files that I am needing to Append.

Thanks!!
Mike Kiser

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The screenshot is too blurry.

If you mean append the content from one blob to another existing blob directly, it is **not supported**. Please see this [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/287593-logic-apps/suggestions/15821374-add-append-blob-api-in-blob-storage-connector).

Logic app supports updating blob and getting blob content. So you could get the contents first and then contact them as a new one, update the new content at last.

Comment: Thanks so much @Pamela! I worked for hours trying to get the Append Blob to work; it seemed to be in the Documentation. Thanks for the clarification. I need to append one blob to another blob in a particular order. Can that be done? Thanks!! Mike Kiser